# check for matching records in a dataset with a regex using a loop

Tags: command-line, bash

I need to create a loop in bash that iterates over a file in order to check that each record matches the following regex, keep the ones that match it and redirect all the ones that match it to a new_file.csv file. There is one particularity and that is that I want the header to be unaffected. That is to say, it must be in the new file

Below you can see an example of the dataset:

```
Country,ISO 3166-1 alpha-3 CODE,Population,Continent,Total Cases,Total Deaths,Tot Cases//1M pop,Tot Deaths/1M pop,Death percentage
Afghanistan,AFG,40462186,Asia,177827,7671,4395,190,4.313743132
Albania,ALB,2872296,Europe,273870,3492,95349,1216,1.275057509
Algeria,DZA,45236699,Africa,265691,6874,5873,152,2.587215976
Andorra,AND,77481,Europe,40024,153,516565,1975,0.382270638
```

For my part, the code I'm trying to run is this but it doesn't even run.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
  if [["$line"=~^[A-Za-z]*,[A-Z]*,[0-9]*,[A-Za-z]*,[0-9]*,[0-9]*,[0-9]*,[0-9]*]]
  then
    $line >> new_file.csv;
  fi
done < dataset.csv
```

I know it can be done with a grep -E of the whole file and redirect it to a new file but I need it to be done with an iterative sequence (for or while). Can someone help me to detect where is the problem?

The error is the following:[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPMv5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before going any further, please read [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

However if you *must* do it this way, the two main issues are

1. `[[` and `]]` are *reserved words* and must be separated from the surrounding tokens by whitespace, as must the `=~` operator
2. `$line >> new_file.csv` does nothing; `>>` redirects standard output, but `$line` doesn't produce standard output

You *probably* also want `read -r` rather than plain `read` in case there are any backslashes in your data.

So

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line =~ ^[A-Za-z]*,[A-Z]*,[0-9]*,[A-Za-z]*,[0-9]*,[0-9]*,[0-9]*,[0-9]* ]]
  then
    printf '%s\n' "$line" >> new_file.csv;
  fi
done < dataset.csv
```

If you want to include the header line in the output, then one simple way would be to add a loop counter:

```
#!/bin/bash
c=0
while read -r line; do
  if (( ++c == 1 )) || [[ $line =~ ^[A-Za-z]*,[A-Z]*,[0-9]*,[A-Za-z]*,[0-9]*,[0-9]*,[0-9]*,[0-9]* ]]
  then
    printf '%s\n' "$line" >> new_file.csv;
  fi
done < dataset.csv
```

In future, you may find [www.shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) helpful for debugging your scripts.

Comment: Hi @steeldriver perfect I'll try it now! and your code avoids reading the header which I want to conserve in the new_file.csv?

Comment: @oshiono so that would be **another** reason why a shell loop is a bad choice here. Probably the simplest option is to add a line counter to the loop so that you can print the first line independent of the regex match.

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't quite see your approach.

Comment: Works perfectly!!! Thank you sooo much!! :)